# CreateProcess ignores lpCurrentDirectory / parent working directory

Tags: c++, winapi, createprocess

I'm trying to use CreateProcess to execute an external process from a c++ application.

The launched application fails when looking for dll's that exist in it's directory.

Inspecting the executwd process with Process Explorer (from sysinternals) shows that the process working directory is c:\windows, and not the parents working directory.

Using lpCurrentDirectory to hard code the working directory also doesn't help.

The process does execute properly qhen using the system command.

*EDIT*
 The problematic directory isn't the module directory, but the current working directory.

The modules directory is searched as expected, but doesn't contain the dll
(Copying the sll to the module directory works -but it,s a workaround)

Comment: The first place that Windows looks when loading DLLs is the directory where the executable module was loaded from. If your DLLs are there then they will be found. The problem clearly isn't quite what you think it is.

Answer (score 2):

When you use CreateProcess function, the first directory searched is the directory containing the image file used to create the calling process.This allows private dynamic-link library (DLL) files associated with a process to be found without adding the process's installed directory to the PATH environment variable. If Dll files are not found, system searches these files in system folders, such as system32 or %windir%.

The search path can be altered using the SetDllDirectory function. This solution is recommended instead of using SetCurrentDirectory or hard-coding the full path to the DLL.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682600%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: What if the launched process is looking for resource files, not DLL ? It also seems to search starting from the directory containing the image file, instead of IpCurrentDirectory, or the parent's current directory. I also tried SetDllDirectory as you suggested, but it had no effect.